# SQL Server JOB Mostrar resultados de una cosulta que lleven mas de 10m saliendo como resultado en la query

Tags: sql, transact-sql, timestamp

Tengo un job corriendo cada 5 minutos en el servidor, necesito filtrar por el timestamp del resultado que este lleve siendo cierto desde hace 4 minutos ¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: puedes ser mas especifico, tu Job, cuando termina escribe una especie de log y quieres consultarlo, o quieres consultar el log de los Jobs, o quieres consultar si se está ejecutando o cuando fue la ultima vez que se ejecutó?

Comment: Leí la pregunta 2 veces y francamente no entiendo lo que quieres hacer. Por favor [edit] y amplía la explicación de lo que quieres lograr y qué dificultad o error tienes para hacerlo. Más información en [ask].